# How to subset evenly spaced samples from a dataframe *without duplicates* in R?

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to create an evenly spaced (in time or in depth) subset of a larger dataset in R. My original data isn't evenly spaced.

These are the functions that need improvement:

```
# calculate step size and subsets df accordingly
spacedSS <- function(df, n, var){
    stp <- (max(var)-min(var))/(n - 1)       #calculate step size
    stps <- min(var)+0:(n-1)*stp             #calculate step values
    res <- lookupDepth(df, stps, var)
    return(as.data.frame(res))
}

# finds values in var closest to stps, returns subsetted df
lookupDepth <- function(df, stps, var){ 
    indxs <- rep(0, times=length(stps)) # create empty index vector
    for(i in seq_along(stps)) {         # for every subsample row
                                        # find the one closest to the step value
                                        # TODO: only if it isn't already in the df
        indxs[i] <- which.min((var - stps[i])^2)
    }
    sampls <- df[indxs, ]               #subset by these new indexes
    return(as.data.frame(sampls))
}
```

And here they are applied to data similar to my own to illustrate the problem:

```
# generate data  
depth <- c(seq(650, 750, length.out = 50), seq(750, 760, length.out = 3),
           seq(760, 780, length.out = 5), seq(780, 800, length.out = 20))
age   <- c(seq(40,  41,  length.out = 50), seq(41,  42,  length.out = 3),
           seq(42,  47,  length.out = 5), seq(47,  48,  length.out = 20))
id    <- seq_along(age)
dat   <- data.frame(id, depth, age)

# subset 10 samples of dat evenly spaced in depth/age
ss.depth <- spacedSS(dat, 10, dat$depth)
ss.age   <- spacedSS(dat, 10, dat$age)
```

Here's a plot of the data:

```
# plot it using my depthplotter function
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/japhir/DepthPlotter/master/DepthPlotter.R")
DepthPlotter(dat[, c("depth", "age")], xlab = "Age (Ma)")
segments(30, ss.depth$depth, ss.depth$age, col = "blue")
segments(ss.age$age, 640, y1 = ss.age$depth, col = "red")
```

[image: show data and illustrate problem]

So the problem I'm trying to solve is that the subset function currently doesn't look at the indeces that are already used:

```
# the problem I'm trying to solve:
length(unique(ss.age$id)) != length(unique(ss.depth$id))
TRUE
# it picked the same samples sometimes because they were the closest ones!
ss.age$id
[1]  1 45 53 55 55 56 57 57 61 78
```

So as you can see, the problem is that when it is subsetting, it currently doesn't take into account the samples that have already been selected. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up asking a friend to help me out, and we've constructed a rather complicated [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) approach.

Basically we created a function to see if there are any duplicate index values, and if so fixes them really simply. A mutation function then randomly changes the index values. The loss of this new subset is checked against the original dataset, random mutations are generated and selected if they are better than the previous selection. The selection criteria are rather loose at first but get more stringent over time, resulting in a pretty cool optimised subset of the data!

If you are interested in the code we used, comment below and we'll put it up somewhere.